# Trying to read in pictures with random order to flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#

I am trying to make for myself a program similar to a memory card game, but for education purposes where you match the word and the definition of that word. So far I successfully understood the following:

1. I am using `FlowLayoutPanel` for the `PictureBox`es, I have over 150 words with descriptions (300+ pictures) so scrolling works and they are next to each other.
2. I can remove with the button1_click picture panels 1 by 1, but I have to remove 1 word and 1 description or it looks weird. As long as they are removed in pair it isn't an issue.

What I want to do and I am stuck with is:

- When I am reading in the pictures, I already want them in random order, for example the picture i provided with just 2 word+description, I would like to have either the words or the descriptions (or both) in a random order so the correct one's arent neccessarily next to each other, but since it's random, there's a slight chance it might happen (the reading in is the following way: pic1, pic1a, pic2, pic2a...picN, picNa)
- When I click on the word that matches the description (like referring to it with name possibly? pic1 and pic1a is clicked on) those 2 `PictureBox`es are removed until there are no `PictureBox` es left to remove.

How it looks for now and the red is how i would like it for example just with that 2:

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    private void pbClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
        int index = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(pictureBox);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(pictureBox);
        //MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();

        // allow multiple selection
        d.Multiselect = true;

        // filter the desired file types
        d.Filter = "JPG |*.jpg|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp";

        // show the dialog and check if the selection was made
        if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string image in d.FileNames)
            {
                // create a new control
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

                // assign the image
                pb.Image = new Bitmap(image);

                // stretch the image
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                // set the size of the picture box
                pb.Height = pb.Image.Height;
                pb.Width = pb.Image.Width;

                // add the control to the container
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);

                pb.Click += pbClick;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed and sorry

Comment: Thanks for the help, edited with your corrections.

Comment: That's better, I've edited your post a little more. Can you edit it somewhat further so it's easier to understand what you need help with?

Comment: Yes, I will try to provide further information. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would associate a word picture with a definition picture.  You need to create a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The code below randomizes the same list twice simulating you strings and pictures.  Then removes the pairs one at a time from the two randomized lists.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>() {
                new Item() { name = "a",  number = 1 },
                new Item() { name = "b",  number = 2 },
                new Item() { name = "c",  number = 3 },
                new Item() { name = "d",  number = 4 },
                new Item() { name = "e",  number = 5 },
                new Item() { name = "f",  number = 6 },
                new Item() { name = "g",  number = 7 },
                new Item() { name = "h",  number = 8 },
                new Item() { name = "i",  number = 9 },
                new Item() { name = "j",  number = 10 },
            };

            Random rand = new Random();
            List<Item> randLetters = items.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.x).ToList();
            List<Item> randNumbers = items.Select((x, i) => new { x = x, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.x).ToList();

            //delete random pairs
            for (int i = randLetters.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                //find matching item in randNumbers and remove from list.
                randNumbers = randNumbers.Where(x => x.name != randLetters[i].name).ToList();
                randLetters.RemoveAt(i);

            }
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
    }
}
```